# Legacy code very strange SESSION behaviour

Tags: php, session

I am working on a symfony project which uses really old legacy code probably from year 2003. I have a strange problem in one of the legacy code function which writes

```
$_SESSION['basket'] = serialize($data);
```

For some reason the `$_SESSION['basket']` only get created during execution and once the script ends `$_SESSION` does not contains the key basket. If I test this in my normal symfony controller it works fine.

What could be the problem for it not storing the key and value?

Comment: session expired or destroyed

Comment: maybe the session is being flushed somewhere u don't know yet. With the backtrace function, you can see all called methods, just like when a exception is throwed... insert the backtrace function at the end of your script and go debuging step by step, checking the session value. Somewhere you will find when the session changed its value.http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.debug-backtrace.php

Comment: I see that function was called from a destructor and I think it is too late to call session from destructor

Comment: I would like to know: What version of PHP is this code running on? imo, If > 5.3 then comment out the 'serialize code' as it will happen automatically. imo, Whatever version of PHP then, the destructor is not the place to serialize. Instead, [Creating a Custom Session Save Handler](http://www.sitepoint.com/writing-custom-session-handlers/) if required. Also, be aware that the class definition must be loaded before the session_start() as It needs the class definition to unserialize it.

Comment: The following code shows that if you call methods or functions in destructor the session value is not saved

http://pastebin.com/EJzXRHJ7